# Connect via Remote Desktop to machine connected to VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, remote-desktop, remote

I have a problem.

I need to connect to a remote machine, which I can do fine. However, once I am on that machine, I need to open a VPN connection to another remote computer. This, I can also do.

The problem resides in if I get disconnected. If I get disconnected, the VPN connection between my remote (RDP) machine and the VPN'd appliance remains intact - when this happens, I can no longer re-establish my connection to my original Remote Desktop machine.

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Is there any set of rules I can apply in my firewall to account for this?

::scratches head::

Thank youre

Comment: Do you have a fixed IP for your local machine, by any chance? Might be worth experimenting with fixed routes to that IP, depending on the exact VPN used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar problem - I use my home workstation as a webserver, ftp server, etc. I keep leaving it VPN'd to my workplace when I need to do something remotely, than forget to leave the VPN when I leave the house, that computer no longer provides its information services.

Tricks I've used so far to regain access to it have been:

-Logging into router via remote management, restarting the router to trigger VPN redial period, during which I can RDP in and cancel (if I'm fast enough)

-VNCing into my hack XP64 2nd computer, then RDPing into my desktop from there, and turning off the VPN.